# Ruby Tsort returning unexpected result

Tags: ruby, sorting

Following the [Tsort docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/TSort.html) simple example:

```rb
require 'tsort'

class Hash
  include TSort
  alias tsort_each_node each_key
  def tsort_each_child(node, &block)
    fetch(node).each(&block)
  end
end
```

When I run it with this dataset, the resulting array seems wrong to me:

```rb
{ 1 => [], 2 => [1], 3 => [2], 4 => [1], 5 => [2] }.tsort
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I was expected one of these arrays instead:

```rb
[1, 4, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
```

Am I misunderstanding `Tsort` or is there something else I'm missing to get to these arrays?

Comment: It looks all right to me: your constraints are that 1 should be before 2 and 4, and that 2 should be before 3 and 5, all of which are satisfied in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` just like they are in the four you posted. Can you explain why the resulting array seems wrong to you? And on what basis you were expecting those four and not the one you got?

Comment: @Amadan that's just how I (mis)understood topological sorting then, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amadan mentioned in the comment nothing is wrong with the result that you retrieve. Topological sort requires that for any edge `u -> v` vertex `u` should precede `v` in the result - and `[1,2,3,4,5]` satisfies this requirement pretty well.

The particular order is determined by the way you traverse the graph. For example, if you slightly change the code so that we would traverse the keys in a reversed order

```rb
require 'tsort'

class Hash
  include TSort

  def tsort_each_child(node, &block)
    fetch(node).each(&block)
  end

  def tsort_each_node(&block)
    each_key.reverse_each(&block)
  end
end
```

the result would be different too:

```
{ 1 => [], 2 => [1], 3 => [2], 4 => [1], 5 => [2] }.tsort
# => [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```

This new result doesn't meet any of your expectations too, but again it fully satisfies the topological sort definition - all nodes appear strictly after their dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, that's actually what I thought was happening and you just confirmed it.